# Finding minmax over set of constrained continuous functions

Tags: probability, optimization

I have this problem that I've been struggling with for a bit, and I don't know how to proceed. I'm looking for the solution to:

$$
\min_f \max_s \frac{\int_s^t f(x) \;dx}{\int_s^\infty f(x)\; dx}
$$

subject to:

$$f(x) \ge 0$$
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) = 1$$
($f$ should be a probability distribution over the non-negative numbers). I have a guess that the solution is the exponential distribution, but I can't seem to demonstrate this conclusively. Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $t$ fixed here?

Comment: @Henry it is greater than $s$. In some personal work, I've set $t = s + \delta$